# Is lock(Application) a good idea when using ASP.NET web service?

Tags: asp.net

I have a collection stored in Application[] state bag in an ASP.NET web service. To prevent the collection from being written to from different methods at the same time, is it OK to surround the code in a

```
lock(Application){}
```

block? I figure that Application is a singleton variable per application, it would make a good candidate as flag. Is there any undesired effects? If so, what is a better way to protect my collection?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with locking Application, exactly for the case like yours. However, it should be done differently, with methods that it conveniently provides:

```
Application.Lock();
Application["key"].Manipulate(); //like update collection or something
Application.Unlock();
```